# Calling apoc procedure from Golang driver

Tags: go, neo4j

I want to call apoc procedure from the golang driver. I can fire basic cypher queries from the driver but while calling apoc procedure it throws a syntax error.

```
panic: An error occurred getting result of exec command: messages.FailureMessage{Metadata:map[string]interface {}{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError", "message":"Invalid input '3': expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', \"=~\", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', \"<>\", \"!=\", '<', '>', \"<=\", \">=\", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ')' (line 1, column 74 (offset: 73))\n\"call apoc.export.json.query(\"MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..] -> (i:node{name:\"39\"}) return p;\",\"2.json\")\"\n


call apoc.export.json.query("MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..] -> (i:node{name:"39"}) return p;","1.json")
```

I want to fire the above query from golang. Basically, golang wants me to pass the query as a string. Here the query itself contains a nested string in it. I think the error is due to that. Below is the syntax I am using to query from golang.

```
conn.PrepareNeo("call apoc.export.json.query(\"MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..] -> (i:node{name:\"39\"}) return p;\",\"1.json\"")
```

Comment: It's very hard to debug code we can't see.

Comment: @Flimzy. Sorry about that. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the trouble, I think. I'd start at the other end of this and work backwards. The query you want to issue (and what you'd type in the Neo4j Browser) is:

```
call apoc.export.json.query("MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..]->(i:node {name: \"39\"}) return p;", "1.json")
```

vs what Neo4j claims you actually sent:

```
call apoc.export.json.query("MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..] -> (i:node{name:"39"}) return p;","1.json")
```

Notice that we've not got any backslashes escaping the quotes around "39" in the Go-generated query.

To fix, we need to emit the backslashes explicitly - I'm not a Go developer so there might be a tidier way of doing this, but in other languages it would be something like:

```
conn.PrepareNeo("call apoc.export.json.query(\"MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..]->(i:node {name: \\\"39\\\"}) return p;\", \"1.json\")")
```

Or use a raw string literal (again, not a Go developer so not certain on this one):

```
conn.PrepareNeo(`call apoc.export.json.query("MATCH t = (p)-[:has*0..]->(i:node {name: \"39\"}) return p;", "1.json")`)
```